# jQuery Mobile input in a popup

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a problem with a form that is partially in a popup [the rest is on the page's main `div`].

```
<body onload="formReset();">
<?php echo "<form action=\"\" method=\"POST\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Main page\"></input></form>"; ?>
<section id="pocetna" data-theme="a" data-role="page" style="background: url('./_images/pekara_bck.jpg'); background-size: auto 700px; background-position: left top; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
<header data-role="header" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <a href="#delpop" data-rel="popup" data-theme="a" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="right">Deliver</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="popup" id="delpop"><a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
        <div style="width: 80%; padding: 15px; margin: 0px auto 0px auto;">
            <?php
                echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"del_name\" maxlength=\"30\" placeholder=\"Your name\" value=\"\"/></br>";
                echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"del_address\" maxlength=\"45\" placeholder=\"Address\" value=\"\"/></br>";
                echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"del_phone\" maxlength=\"30\" placeholder=\"Phone\" value=\"\"/></br>";
                echo "<textarea name=\"del_note\" rows=\"5\" style=\"resize: none; width: 80% height: 150px\" placeholder=\"Note\"></textarea>";
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

The popup works, but when submitted, only the fields that were outside the popup where posted.

**PS:** -The form opening tag is just after the body tag, so it does include the popup.
    -One more thing. I need these fields in a pop up. This works when the fields are not in a popup, and don't when they are in a popup. Is there a way to make them work, but still be in a popup?

Comment: I'm not sure on the intricacies of the jQuery Mobile popup as I've not used them, but does it remove it from the page when it's closed?

Comment: It does remove the popup from the page, but since it uses a div as a popup, my thinking was it just `display: hidden`-s it.

Comment: I see the problem now, as does cillosis, below.  Out of curiosity, why put the form tag in a php echo, rather than just put the tag in the html?  Come to think of it, why are you using php echo for any of the html tags in the code above?

Comment: Work in progress :] eventually the content will change according to previous page form inputs. But the `<form>` tag being in php is a mistake. Not that it doesn't work, but yeah, it's unnecessary :]

Comment: One more thing. Should i delete the question, since it was a small copy paste error that was the problem? It will not be of much use to others, as far as I can see.

Comment: I don't know if you can delete your own question yet, but I think you're right.

Comment: Thank you for your help and support :]
I'll try to delete the post now.

Comment: No worries - glad you got it fixed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the fields to be inside the `<form>` element in order to post them as data. On this line:

```
<?php echo "<form action=\"\" method=\"POST\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Main page\"></input></form>"; ?>
```

You can't close the form yet. Instead...

```
<?php echo "<form action=\"\" method=\"POST\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Main page\"></input>"; ?>
     // Put your popup here in the middle with input elements.
<?php echo "</form>"; ?>
```

Comment: Tnx, replacing the `<?php echo "<form action=\"\" method=\"POST\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Main page\"></input></form>"; ?>` line with `<?php echo "<form id=\"por\" action=\"prosledi.php\" method=\"post\" autocomplete=\"off\">"; ?>` did it. My mistake. Copied the wrong form there. Thank you for pointing that out and answering.